# Function that applies two given functions to an outside argument in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, lambda

I'm going through some interview prep questions a college advisor gave me and this question was suggested as being prepared for different interviews:

> "Complete the function:

```
applyFunctions(outer_function, inner_function)
```

> which takes two functions, an outer and an inner, and returns a function which applies the outer function to the inner function to an argument."

I'm somewhat puzzled by this question, given that it does not accept the argument in the function, but instead is applied outside of it:

```
applyFunctions(outer_function, inner_function)(5)
```

I am familiar with lambda and its uses, but this question has stumped me.

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

A test case (example) included is:

```
add2 = lambda x: x + 2
times2 = lambda x: x * 2

compose(add2,times2)(3)

> 8
```

Comment: that's the whole question? it doesn't mention anything about the implementation of `outer_function` and `inner_function`?

Comment: I edited the original question to include an example. Everything there is what is included in the question. @OmarEinea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First define what `inner` and `outer` are: functions that take an argument and return a result.

Then define `apply`, a function that takes two functions, and returns a function that combines the two in some manner.

```
def inner(n):
    print("inner called")
    return 3 * n

def outer(n):
    print("outer called")
    return n - 5

def apply(inn, out):
    return lambda n: out(inn(n))


a = apply(inner, outer)
print(a(5))
```

output:

```
10
```

Answer (score 2):

What they mean is: make a function that, given `f` and `g`, makes a function that takes `x` and gives `f(g(x))`. A function that takes `f` and `g` looks like `lambda f,g:<something>` A function that takes `x` is `lambda x:<something>`. Putting it together, you have `lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda to create a new function that passes all of *args and **kwargs to inner_function, which returns to outer_function:

```
def applyFunctions(outer_function, inner_function):
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: outer_function(inner_function(*args, **kwargs))
```